# What would cause an autorenewing itunes subscription to not renew?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

We use autorenewing in app purchases to allow our users to buy our Premium offering, some of which start with a 30 day free trial.  Recently, a user was downgraded from an in app purchase with a free trial because their subscription did not renew.  It was an autorenewing subscription, so I'm trying to figure out why that happened. Here's what we know.

- Their credit card had not expired (confirmed with them)
- They were not billed by strava
- They received no communications from Apple
- They found out about their downgrade when they received the email from us alerting them to it.

What else could be causing this? I haven't seen this happen before. Thanks a ton!

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KolIU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the price of your auto-renewable subscription the user must enable the subscription plan again. If you decrease the price the subscription will continue.